# React Navigation same screen in different navigators

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

TL;DR version : Regarding navigation, how does one handle having the same screen in multiple different navigators ?

Long version :

I have a quite complex app made in React Native app, using React Navigation (social network type), with multiple nested navigators, depending on what the user is doing (registering, login, loading, using the app). The app basicaly allows you to share your experience in various places (who you are with, what you're drinking, etc). Those places have a dedicated profile screen that you can access.

When logged in, I have a bottom tab navigator that leads to the four main sections of the app : feed, post new content, search, user profile.

Each of those sections have a specific stack navigator.

My issue is that some screens can be accessed in multiples sections. I'll take a specific example but it applies to many screens. So, the "Place profile" screen can be accessed through the feed when you click on the place name, from the
search, when you search places, or from the user profile (because we list the user posts, and those posts can have a place mentionned).

I first tried to say that it belongs to the feed navigator and everytime a place is clicked, we move back to the feed tab and to the place screen. It works fine until I click on the "related places" link that opens the map in the search section. The back button (that use `navigation.goBack()`) goes back in the search stack instead of the global navigation history.

I then tried to add every potential screens to every needing section navigators. Back button is working fine, but I'm having navigation issues now when trying to go to a screen that belongs only to a specific navigator. For those, I then specified the "owner" of it (using `navigation.navigate("Foo", { screen: "Bar", params: { baz: buz }})`), but I'm having weird navigations results where the navigator state is preserved between tab navigations, despite using unmountOnBlur. Also, that solution is ugly as hell with typescript.

I thought of doing a generic screen version, that would be hosted by a specific parent screen that would handle the navigation. But I'm then required to inject so many things from that parent screen (I need the navigation object in almost every component) which also leads to another typescript hell.

Also, almost every screen and complex component is a class component and not a functionnal one. No debate on the topic, it is as it is and can't be changed, so useNavigation() is out of the realm of possibilites right now (even with a HOC).

Comment: While it doesn't answer my question, I found out why I was having weird back button issues, it was coming from two screens in nested navigators that had the same name.